# Number of $n$-digit binary numbers such that no two zeroes are consecutive

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

> Let $a_n$ denote the number of $n$-digit binary numbers such that no two zeroes are consecutive. Is $a_{17}=a_{16}+a_{15}$?

Let $a_n$ denote the number of $n$-digit binary numbers such that no two zeroes are consecutive.

$$a_1=2$$
$$a_2=3$$
$a_3$ can contain one $1$, two $1$s or all $1$s.

$$a_3=1+\frac{3!}{2!}+1=5$$
$$a_4=0+3+4=7$$
$$a_5=0+0+6+5+1=12$$

I don't see any relation connecting the above $a_i$s. The number of possibilities depend on the number of $1$s. Should I calculate $a_n$?

Comment: Be careful:  $a_4 = 8$, $a_5 = 13$.  With those corrections, the terms of the sequence should look familiar.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig you mean 2,3,5,8,13,...? I have never seen them. It's not AP, Gp or HP. Their common differences are also not in AP.

Comment: They are terms of the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of $n$-digit binary numbers such that no two zeroes are consecutive.

Consider the last digit of the $n$-digit binary number.

---

Case 1: The last digit is $1$

In this case, the first $n-1$ digits must satisfy the condition that no two zeroes are consecutive. There are $a_{n-1}$ ways in which they can do so, thus the total number of $n$-digit binary numbers with no two zeroes consecutive and ending with $1$ is $a_{n-1}$.

---

Case 2: The last digit is $0$

In this case, the last but one digit cannot be zero, as it would violate the given condition. Thus, the last but one digit must be $1$. There are now $a_{n-2}$ ways in which the first $n-2$ digits can satisfy the given condition. Thus, the number of $n$-digit binary numbers with no two zeroes consecutive and ending with $0$ is $a_{n-2}$.

---

This thus gives the recurrence relation,
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$
It is easy to verify that $a_0=1,a_1=2$, which are the base cases.

Comment: The empty sequence does not contain two consecutive zeros.  Hence, $a_0 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

To see the recursion you want:  Let $b_n$ be the number of such sequences that end in $0$, and $c_n$ the number that end in $1$.  We have $$a_n=b_n+c_n$$

It is easy to see that $$c_n=a_{n-1}\;\;\&\;\;b_n=c_{n-1}\implies b_n=a_{n-2}$$

Comment: Can you suggest a book for learning recursions?  (Or a website).

Comment: In the past I have recommended these note:  http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4205/files/CM2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

$a_n$ number of n-digit binary numbers with no two consecutive 0s, which start with 1
$b_n$ number of n-digit binary numbers with no two consecutive 0s, which start with 0

Then:

$a_n = b_{n-1} + a_{n-1}$
$b_n = a_{n-1}$

Try to prove why these are true.
So it leads to a recursion on two sequences (very nice).