# Recurrence Relation Problem: Words of length $n$ from the digits $\{0, 1\}$ with with no two consecutive zeros

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Given the following problem:

> If $a_n$ is the number of words of length $n$ formed using the digits $\{0, 1\}$ that does  not have two consecutive zeros. Find a recurrence relation to calculate $a_n$ and resolve it.

*What I've tried?*

I know that the condition is only valid for, $n \ge 2$.

- $n = 0$: There is only one way to make any selection.
- $n = 1$: There are $2$ possible words. $\{ 0, 1 \}$.
- $n = 2$: **I followed the following principle:**

$$
* \rightarrow \text{placement of two consecutive zeros.} \\
2^n \text{ possible combinations,} \\
2^{n - 2} * \text { number of ways that two consecutive zeros can be placed. } \\
-\\
\text{from __ __ which is } 2^2 = 4 \text{ possible combinations,} \\
\text{we have * = } 2^0 * 1 = 1 \text { possibilities of word with two consecutive zeros. } \\
\text{Therefore we have } 2^2 - 2^0 * 1 = 4 - 1 = 3 \text{ words with no consecutive zeros.}
$$

- $n = 3$:

$$
\text{from __ __ __ which is } 2^3 = 8 \text{ possible combinations,} \\
\text{we have { * __, __ * } = } (2^1 * 2 = 4 \text { possibilities of word with two consecutive zeros. } \\
\text{Therefore we have } 2^3 - 2^1 * 2 = 8 - 4 = 4 \text{ words with no consecutive zeros.}
$$

- $n = 4$:

$$
\text{from __ __ __ __ which is } 2^4 = 16 \text{ possible combinations,} \\
\text{we have { * __ __, __ * __, __ __ * } = } (2^2 * 3 = 12 \text { possibilities of word with two consecutive zeros. } \\
\text{Therefore we have } 2^4 - 2^2 * 3 = 16 - 12 = 4 \text{ words with no consecutive zeros.}
$$

Which I know is incorrect. Is this a good approach? If so where did I go wrong and if not, what is the best way to go about solving this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Induction) $n$-digit binary numbers that have no consecutive $1$'s is the Fibonacci number $F_{n+2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935926/induction-n-digit-binary-numbers-that-have-no-consecutive-1s-is-the-fibon)

Comment: See also [Recurrence relation for number of bit strings of length n that contain two consecutive 1s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671982/number-of-n-digit-binary-numbers-such-that-no-two-zeroes-are-consecutive?rq=1) or [Recurrence Relation for Bit String Length n with No Consecutive 0s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974505/recurrence-relation-for-bit-string-length-n-with-no-consecutive-0s?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n$ denote the number of bit strings of length $n$ that don’t have two consecutive $0$s.

> Note that the **number of such bit strings equals the number of bit strings ending with a $0$ plus the number of bit strings ending with a $1$.** We will assume $n \geq 3$.

The bit strings of length $n$ ending with $1$ that do not have two consecutive $0$s equals the number of bit strings of length $n-1$ with no consecutive $0$s with a $1$ added at the end. There are $a_{n-1}$ such bit strings.

Bit strings of length $n$ ending with a $0$ that do not have two consecutive $0$s must have a $1$ as the second last digit. It folllows that they equal the number of bit strings of length $n-2$ with no two consecutive $0$s  with $10$ added at the end. There are $a_{n-2}$ such bit strings.

Hence, $$\boxed{a_n = a_{n-1}+ a_{n-2}\,\,, n\geq 3}$$

---

One can notice that as $a_1=2$ and $a_2=3$, the sequence is the well-known Fibonacci sequence: $$a_n = f_{n+2}$$